# How to do css animation-delay?

Tags: css

I'm trying to, on `li:hover`, have one child `<div>` animate its width, at x seconds, from 0 to 100% and then a given number of seconds later animate another `div` the exact same way.

This is my code and it isn't working the way that I want it to.

```
li {
    margin-bottom: -1px;

    #top, #bottom {
        height: 1px;
        width: 0;
        display: block;
        background: $white;
    }

    #bottom {
        -o-transition:.25s;
        -ms-transition:.25s;
        -moz-transition:.25s;
        -webkit-transition:.25s;
        transition:.25s;
    }

    #top {
        -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards; /* Opera */
        animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards;
    }

    &:hover {
        #bottom {
            -o-transition:.25s;
            -ms-transition:.25s;
            -moz-transition:.25s;
             -webkit-transition:.25s;
            transition:.25s;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #top {
            -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards; /* Firefox */
            -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards; /* Opera */
            animation: fadein 3s ease-in 3s forwards;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide your html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the animation property without defining [keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp).